# Duplicate title and meta description

Tags: google-search-console

Recently I found out from Webmaster Tools, one of my blogs has 154 duplicate title and 156 duplicate meta description. On closer look, both URLs lead to the same blog post. One is with the date followed by the blog title and the other begins with the blog title. Example:

```
/2011/06/blog title.html 
/blog title/
```

Is it something to do with the permalink settings? What should I do now?

Comment: What content management system (CMS) are you using to host your blog?  Is it WordPress?  There are likely plugins available that will implement the canonical tag for you as suggested by Custom Clicks.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a preferred version of the page and use the [canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) as this will help to remove duplicate content.

The way to use this is to include it in the `<head>` section of your duplicate pages and point the href to the preferred version of the page as so...

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/preferred-url.html"/>
```

You should ensure only your preferred pages appear in the sitemap and your internal linking structure points to these preferred links.

In an ideal world you would also 301 redirect all versions of your page to the preferred version as this would consolidate the value of the page, however this can sometimes be less practical.

Comment: Am I right to say that i need to go all those blog posts to add a conical tag as suggested above to rectify the problem?

Comment: What I meant is I need to add a long list of canonical tag in the header.php, right?

Comment: If you have the two versions of the page mentioned above, you would choose one version, eg) if your preferred page is: /2011/06/blog title.html, on both pages you would add <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/2011/06/blog title.html"/>. Each page should only have one canonical tag and all pages with identical content should canonical to the same page.